# Salary negotiations when going from intern, to part time student work, to full time

Tags: salary, internship, negotiation, promotion

Heyo, Currently I'm working as a software developer intern. The salary is alright, and I'm working 40 hours a week.

I'm going to be offered a full time role. However, I've still got a year of college left. The company is willing to extend the internship so I can work part time during the school year before going full time.

**My question is, should I try negotiating my salary when transitioning to part time work as a student?**

My current salary as an intern is significantly less than what a full time equivalent makes - and I'm worried that not negotiating a raise now might kneecap my ability to negotiate when I'm hired full time. I also genuinely believe that I deserve to earn more, even as a part time employee.

I should note that notable raises when going from intern to full time are normal at this company.

Tl;dr: transitioning from Intern to part time (While a student) and then eventually full time. Should I try to negotiate a raise now?

Comment: I actually don't understand the details of the question.  But **yes** you should **always** politely and firmly negotiate your salary.  Be aware that the one, and only, rule of negotiation is you have to be prepared to walk away if you don't get what you want.  And the one and only way to "be prepared to walk away" (if you're not independently wealthy) is to have another opportunity lined-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Internship is a special program. When the program takes an end you should discuss the new role on a completely separate notes where you use your prior experience (in this case the internship, for example) as a justification for perks such as higher salary.

There are a number of great answers here on the workplace that you should take a look at on how to negotiate salary, I'll not get into details here as that would make a duplicate.